# external microphone on double jack (mic/headphones)

Tags: 13.10, microphone, audio-jack

I would like to use my microphone on my laptop.
But my laptop only have a single jack, mic + headphones combined.
When I plug my microphone, the system think it's an headphone. (sound is muted from speakers)
How can i force the system to use this as an mic ?

(In sound settings, i have only one "Input", my internal mic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need an adapter to connect a microphone since the jack is not directly compatible with a microphone, instead you can connect a normal headphone directly. These adapters have a male 4 pin and two female 3 pin connectors. You can get them at your favorite electronics parts dealer.

Comment: I don't know much about jack and his family. But I was able to use 4 pin headset by adding "options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-dmic" into "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf". So i guess now i just need this 4->3 adaptor and it should work too. Thanks !!!

Comment: I have the same problem...I'll try the adapter tomorrow... let's hope for the best